# How do I create a key at mashape.com?

Tags: asp.net, sms, mashape

I am trying to send SMS from asp.net web application (free SMS). Upon searching, I found this article :

[How to send SMs from ASP.Net application](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-send-free-SMS-from-ASPNet-application-to-Mobile.aspx)

Now, according to the article I am trying to create a key at mashape.com . But I am unable to do the same.

can someone help?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create an application through the header (or directly on an api profile, see dropdown below)

[image: Generate application]

Now you have two ways to get the key:

- Navigate to your application and click the button that says `Get the keys`, a modal will appear that contains a key management center. There you can generate keys, and block previous keys.

[image: Get the keys button]

- Going on the api, and now you should see a dropdown where you can select the application, the key for the application selected will be in the adjacent code snippet.

[image: Key inside of code snippet]

:)